# StrSubstitute can not replace characters

Tags: xstring

I would like to dynamically display different content according to the macro name, I can not achieve this through the following way：

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
x`list
A`Macroone,Macrotwo
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forarray}
\usepackage{ctex}

\DTLsetseparator{`}
\DTLloaddb{tabscores}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLgetvalue{\score}{tabscores}{1}{2}

\newenvironment{Macroone}[1]{Column1<t>Column 2 and  param is #1}{}
\newenvironment{Macrotwo}[1]{Column1<t>Column 2 and  param is #1}{}

%Get the parameter to replace the character，but did not succeed
\newcommand{\testprintstring}[1]{
    \noexpandarg
    \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{#1}{<t>}{`}[\item]
    \item %<T> is not replaced by `

}
\begin{document}
  %Retrieve the corresponding content as a parameter based on the macro name    
  \ForEachX{,}{
    \testprintstring{\begin{\thislevelitem}{param}\end{\thislevelitem}}
  }{\score}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
 Column1Column 2 and  param is param  Column1Column 2 and  param is param

Comment: Your definition would simply expand `\begin`; what's `\thislevelitem`?

Comment: The value of \ thislevelitem is Macro, which is one of the strings of Macro <t> Macro. I would like to pass the macro name to get the corresponding content as a parameter passed to another macro to separate。@egreg

Comment: Can you please explain what's the intended behavior? As it is, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\begin{Macro}{param}\end{Macro}}{<t>}{`}[\item]  The <t> in the string is not replaced with the `character ,Replace \ long {mand} {param} \ end {Macro} with \ Macro {param}, but how to dynamically stitch \ Macro {param}?\backslash\thislevelitem?It is wrong to put together this。

Comment: I don't think you want to have ``\ForEachX{`}{...}{...}`` in the document body.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve my thoughts@egreg

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand what you're after.

Comment: I want to replace the <t> symbol in the Macroone or Macrotwo string, but the Macroone or Macroone name is read from the cvs file, and the content is expanded by \ begin {Macroone} \ end {Macroone}, but it is passed as a parameter to the testprintstring Macro can not be expanded, resulting in <t> characters can not be replaced @ egreg